PCL Crop Hull setCropOuside not working
Experimenting with Crop Hull. It works as expected but when I try to invert the cropping, setCropOutside(true), it doesn't work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Running ROS2, Humble, PCL 1.12.1
This is the code I have, just playing with a cube:
inputPcdMsg is of type ensor_msgs::msg::PointCloud2 coming from a ROS topic
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr inputCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
pcl::fromROSMsg(*inputPcdMsg, *inputCloud);
    
// Filtered cloud
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr filtered_cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);

// Create hull
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr boundingbox_ptr (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(-2., -2., -1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ( 2., -2., -1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(-2.,  2., -1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ( 2.,  2., -1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(-2., -2., 1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ( 2., -2., 1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ(-2.,  2., 1.0 ));
boundingbox_ptr->push_back(pcl::PointXYZ( 2.,  2., 1.0 ));

// Make convex hull
pcl::ConvexHull<pcl::PointXYZ> hull;
hull.setInputCloud(boundingbox_ptr);

// Construct the hull
hull.reconstruct(*boundingbox_ptr);

// Apply filter
pcl::CropHull<pcl::PointXYZ> hull_filter_;
hull_filter_.setInputCloud(inputCloud);      
hull_filter_.setHullCloud(convex_hull);
hull_filter_.setDim(3);
hull_filter_.setCropOutside(true);
hull_filter_.filter(*filtered_cloud);

Without hull_filter_.setCropOutside(true) I get the point cloud in the cube as expected, but setting it to true I get an almost empty cloud, I do see some points in a corner, which makes me think something weird is going on but I have no idea what the problem could be.
